# Python recursion with an int different than with a list?

Tags: python, recursion

Kind of a python novice, so please bear with me. I have two code snippets in python:

```
def summer(step, track, lst):
    if track<10:
        lst.append(1)
        summer(step,track+step,lst)
    return lst
```

calling summer(1,1,[]) returns

```
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
```

Now lets say I have:

```
def summer(step, track):
    if track<10:
        track +=step
        summer(step,track)
    return track
```

calling summer (1,1) returns 2

Notice the similarity between these two snippets, in the first one I'm appending to a list and at the end returning that list. It works as intended.

In the second one, I'm instead incrementing a variable, but at the end when I return it, it does not work as intended (returns 2 when it should return 11). I understand this is because in the second snippet I'm recursively calling

```
summer(step,track)
```

When I should be saying

```
return summer(step,track)
```

But why is it that in the first snippet, I can simply call

```
summer(step,track+step,lst)
```

instead of

```
return summer(step,track+step,lst)
```

and it still works? i.e. it seems that keeping track of a list and an int in recursion is treated differently?

Comment: In your second snippet, the return value from summer never gets assigned to anything and gets thrown away.

Comment: It's a real code smell to modify a parameter and also return it. Please don't do that, unless you're sure that modifications to the parameter will remain local to the function.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The difference is that lists are mutable and ints are not. The line

```
lst.append(1)
```

modifies the *object* that `lst` refers to. The line

```
track += step
```

is identical to `track = track + step` because `track` refers to an immutable object (an `int`). As a result, the local name `track` is just set to a new object, rather than somehow modify the object that was passed as an argument to `summer()`.

Although `+=` is *intended* to be an in-place operator, there is no strict requirement that it be so. `int.__iadd__` returns a new `int` object precisely because an `int` is immutable, and therefore it is not possible to modify it.

Comment: Just a note, `__iadd__` always results in an assignment, which is why it's supposed to return a reference to the original object (`return self`) for mutable objects or a new object (`return value`) for immutable. In otherwords, `__iadd__` isn't just *like* `a = a+b`, it is *exactly* `a = class.__iadd__(a,b)`.

Comment: I never thought about it until now, but when does it matter *what* `__iadd__` returns? You can't chain augmented assignments, and I can't think of any place where one can be used as an expression.

Comment: Oh, right, if it gets called explicitly. Another case where Python's semantics are much broader than the syntax can support :)

Comment: It's doing it even when you don't chain them. Try returning `None` (or just forgetting a return) and you'll find that every object you use `+=` on is suddenly set to `None`.

Comment: The `a += b` operator is syntactic sugar for `a = class.__iadd__(a,b)`. The only reason they don't just use `a = class.__add__(a,b)` is to allow you to have different behavior for the mutability of `+` and `+=` (I.E. make `+` return a new object, but `+=` modify the existing object). `list` exhibits this behavior; `+` creates a new list that is the union of the two operands, but `+=` modifies the left operand in-place.

Comment: Good to know, clearly I've rarely, if ever, defined `__iadd__` myself or thought about how it gets used.

Comment: This can also lead to subtle bugs in your code if you define `__iadd__` in terms of `__add__` and `__add__` returns a new object. While the `a` in `a+=b` would in fact be the same as calling `a = a + b`, any alias of `a` would now no longer reference the same object, so you haven't actually modified the object in-place, you've just assigned a new value to the same name.

Answer (score 1):

So a `list` is not passed as value, whereas `int` is. So you are modifying the actual list in your recursive calls, whereas your int before the call is not the same int being modified in your recursive calls.

Comment: Technically they're both passed by reference, but `int` is immutable, so the only way you can modify it is via an assignment which would replace the reference with a reference to a new value. So essentially pass-by-value, but an important difference since int is arbitrary precision and pass by value would imply a copy.

Answer (score 0):

@chepner has already provided a wonderful explanation to justify the difference in the observable behavior. On a different note, I would like to touch on two patterns that you can use, which in future would leave less scope of confusion in regards to usage of mutable/im-mutable variables.

```
>>> def summer(step, track, lst):
    if track<10:
        return summer(step,track+step,lst + [1])
    else:
        # Trivial Case
        return lst

>>> summer(1,1,[])
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
>>> 
>>> def summer(step, track):
    if track<10:
        return summer(step,track + step)
    else:
        # Trivial Case
        return track

>>> summer (1,1)
10
```

As you can see, both the approaches looks quite similar, has no separate handling for mutable and immutable objects, and returns the result accurately.

So the important thing to note is, in a recursive pattern,

1. never ignore a return value of a function call, if the function should eventually return a value.
2. never mix a trivial with a non-trivial case and make the distinction explicit
3. If you modify a variable, do not expect that the value would percolate downwards to the caller. Such behavioral patterns are difficult to debug and analyze